# what is the best approach to capture the MTU value

Tags: linux, bash, networking, rhel, ifconfig

I am using the follwing to find the mtu value

```
ifconfig | grep mtu
eno17832: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
```

but in my bash script we want to know exactly the MTU value

so we can use this

```
MTU_VAL=` ifconfig | grep mtu | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' `
```

but this may be risky and no so elegant

please let me know if we can capture the MTU for sure ?

Comment: *exactly the MTU value* - each ethernet interface has its own `mtu` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most tools leverage information present in /proc or /sys, concerning ifconfig I'd go with `/sys/class/net/<interface>/*` files:

To get mtu for all interfaces but loopback (`lo`) this would work:

```
cat /sys/class/net/[^l][^o]*/mtu
```

The exclusion is done by shell globing, anything not starting with l then o is expanded and then the mtu file within it is read. If there's only one interface other than loopback it will return its mtu as a single value, usable in script with `$()` to put the output in a variable.

To answer the comment:

```
$ awk '{split(FILENAME,arr,"/"); print arr[5],$1}' /sys/class/net/*/mtu
ens160 1500
lo 65536
```

Same pattern match as above to exclude `lo` if needed (I've kept it here to showcase multiple interface output).

Comment: this is nice way , can we get the interface name and mtu value on each line?

Comment: @yael this highly sounds like an XY problem, what are you willing to do with this information ?

Answer (score 1):

Read from its config value directly.

```
MTU_VAL=$(< /sys/class/net/<replace-with-interface-name>/mtu)
```

Just replace `<replace-with-interface-name>` with the interface-name you want its MTU.